# How to get the original text, if I forget the key

Tags: java

Through the below mentioned program I have encrypted the text using the key and also decrypted the same using the same key but what if, if I forget the key, then how can i get my original text?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;
/** 
 * Encryption and Decryption of String data; PBE(Password Based Encryption and Decryption)
 * @author Vikram
 */
public class CryptoUtil {

    Cipher ecipher;
    Cipher dcipher;
    // 8-byte Salt
    byte[] salt = {
        (byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x32,
        (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x03
    };
    // Iteration count
    int iterationCount = 19;
    public CryptoUtil() { 

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param secretKey Key used to encrypt data
     * @param plainText Text input to be encrypted
     * @return Returns encrypted text
     * 
     */
    public String encrypt(String secretKey, String plainText) 
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
            InvalidKeySpecException, 
            NoSuchPaddingException, 
            InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, 
            UnsupportedEncodingException, 
            IllegalBlockSizeException, 
            BadPaddingException{
        //Key generation for enc and desc
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);        
         // Prepare the parameter to the ciphers
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);

        //Enc process
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);      
        String charSet="UTF-8";       
        byte[] in = plainText.getBytes(charSet);
        byte[] out = ecipher.doFinal(in);
        String encStr=new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(out);
        return encStr;
    }
     /**     
     * @param secretKey Key used to decrypt data
     * @param encryptedText encrypted text input to decrypt
     * @return Returns plain text after decryption
     */
    public String decrypt(String secretKey, String encryptedText)
     throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
            InvalidKeySpecException, 
            NoSuchPaddingException, 
            InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, 
            UnsupportedEncodingException, 
            IllegalBlockSizeException, 
            BadPaddingException, 
            IOException{
         //Key generation for enc and desc
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);        
         // Prepare the parameter to the ciphers
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);
        //Decryption process; same key will be used for decr
        dcipher=Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key,paramSpec);
        byte[] enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedText);
        byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(enc);
        String charSet="UTF-8";     
        String plainStr = new String(utf8, charSet);
        return plainStr;
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CryptoUtil cryptoUtil=new CryptoUtil();
        String key="ezeon8547";   
        String plain="This is an important message";
        String enc=cryptoUtil.encrypt(key, plain);
        System.out.println("Original text: "+plain);
        System.out.println("Encrypted text: "+enc);
        String plainAfter=cryptoUtil.decrypt(key, enc);
        System.out.println("Original text after decryption: "+plainAfter);
    }
}
```

But if I forget the key then how can I get my original text which I have encrypted. Please suggest.

Comment: You would have to break the encryption. Good luck

Comment: *"But if I forget the key then how can I get my original text which I have encrypted."* If you could do that, anyone could do it, and it would be ***really poor encryption***, wouldn't it?!

Comment: The actual scenario is I have created a java web application in which i can store my username password. Before storing the password in database I have encrypted that password using the key and I can decrypt that password with the same key. But if I change the key then how can i get my password (or how can i decrypt my password)

Comment: @MaxSteel You need to put in some data migration step where you convert the entire database between the two keys. That said; passwords aren't supposed to be decryptable (since they are hashed not encrypted)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to crack the key in the same manner as anyone else who didn't know the key.

You can do

- brute force, try every possible key.
- dictionary lookup, in case it's not a random key.

Note: this assumes you have a way of recognising the data as decrypted when it has been.  If the original data is random, and there is no way to know it has been decrypted, there is no way to crack it.

What normally, happens when you lose a key to a lock, you have to break something.

BTW Depending on the encryption, keys might not be unique. It is possible that multiple keys could unlock the data in which case, it's not possible to know the original key, only one or more key which can unlock the data.

e.g. unix systems used to only use the first 8 letters of a password.  This meant if your password was longer than 8, it was possible to crack the first 8 letters, but there was no way to know if the password was longer and which letters were discarded.

Comment: The actual scenario is I have created a java web application in which i can store my username password. Before storing the password in database I have encrypted that password using the key and I can decrypt that password with the same key. But if I change the key then how can i get my password (or how can i decrypt my password).

Comment: @MaxSteel Normally passwords are encrypted in a manner which cannot be easily decrypted by any means, instead you only want to know if the correct password is encrypted.  You can make the password easily decryptable however, this is far less secure.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! means I have to store the key very safely if I do not want to lose my password.

Comment: @MaxSteel I suggest you make your password something you couldn't possibly forget. ;)